# how to add button for every TableRow dynamically using Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, tablelayout, tablerow

i know its easy question but i am newbie .....i want to add button for every row e.g for row1 there should be button1 and for row2 there should be button2 , buttons insertion and text are controlled using for loop
**first.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/summaryHeaderLinear_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/summaryTable_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
    </TableLayout>
```

**firstrow.xml**

```
 <TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/summary_tablerow"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/summaryHeader_linearlayout"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/summaryHeader_firstlinearlayout"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/summaryHeader_secondlinearlayout"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/summaryHeader_thirdlinearlayout"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">
  </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

**firstRow.java:**

```
     setContentView(R.layout.first);
     summaryTableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.summaryTable_layout);
     summaryInflator = getLayoutInflater();
     for(int i =0;i<2;i++)
    {   final TableRow summaryTableRow = (TableRow)summaryInflator.inflate(R.layout.firstrow,null);
LinearLayout summaryHeaderLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)summaryTableRow.findViewById(R.id.summaryHeader_linearlayout);
summaryTableRow.setId(i);
Button summaryBtn = new Button(this);
summaryBtn.setId(i);
summaryBtn.setText("sample button:" +i);
summaryBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
summaryTableRow.addView(summaryBtn);
 for(int k=0;k<5;k++)
{
LinearLayout summaryFirstHorizontalLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)summaryTableRow.findViewById(R.id.summaryHeader_firstlinearlayout);
TextView newText = new TextView(this);
newText.setId(k);
newText.setText(topRowArray[k]);
newText.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f));
newText.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
newText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
summaryFirstHorizontalLinearLayout.addView(newText);
 }
summaryTableLayout.addView(summaryTableRow);
}
```

the output of code is:
   [image: code snaphot]
**while i want to create this layout:**

```
 Button for row1
      name qty cost sell margin
  Button for row2
     name qty cost sell margin
```

but its not displaying like this i already have defined separate xml i dnt want to create dynamic Row.I want to use defined firstrow.xml please help me what should i need to do changes in my existing code

Comment: You can add them via code dynamically. See @ravi-patel answer below. But for this kind of layout, the Androids have created `ListView`. Would that be an option?

Answer (score 0):

use to a dynamically add textview and button on linearlayout

```
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
    for(int y =0;y<5;y++){
        TextView textv= new TextView(this);
        final Button myButton = new Button(this);

        textv.setText("record");
        myButton.setText("button"+y);
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.addView(textv,lp);
        ll.addView(myButton,lp);
}
```

i think this are usefull your problem solution

Comment: can u please help me how can i create using TableRow

Comment: hello Mr. i not your employee , i can only to segues this process are to dynamically add button using this code to create new own requirement code ok